# EditText prefix for each line

Tags: android, android-edittext

When user input text in EditText needs to automatically add to each line prefix "*".

**Example:**

*line first some text

*second line with some text

**How can I do that ?**

Comment: Do you want it to be part of the actual text; i.e., copyable, deletable, etc.? Or do you want it to be more like the line numbers in your IDE?

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for response. I want that when a user enters / deleted some text in the field to each line added at the beginning of the symbol.

Comment: Right, but say I select and copy the first line in your example. Should it copy "\*line first some text", or just "line first some text", without the asterisk? That is, is the "\*" part of the editable text? If yes, can it be deleted?

Comment: @MikeM. if copy text it would be copy without symbol *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want the asterisk to be part of the editable text, we can just draw it at the beginning of each line. To do this, we subclass `EditText` and override the `onDraw()` method, iterating over the lines, and figuring each line's bounds to determine where to draw the character. After drawing the asterisks, we then call the `super.onDraw()` method to allow the `EditText` to finish drawing the text, cursor, selection, etc.

```
public class StarredEditText extends EditText {
    private static final String ASTERISK = "*";

    private float padding;
    private Paint paint;

    public StarredEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public StarredEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = getPaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int baseline;
        final int count = getLineCount();

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            baseline = getLineBounds(i, null);
            canvas.drawText(ASTERISK, padding, baseline, paint);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        getLineBounds(0, rect);
        padding = (rect.left - paint.measureText(ASTERISK)) / 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to happen as the user is typing then use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) with the `onTextChanged()` or `afterTextChanged()` callback.

Or if you want it after they have changed the text and moved on to the next `EditText` you can just take the value and prefix the asterisk yourself.

In your `afterTextChanged()` you can do something along the lines of:

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!s.toString().startsWith("*")){
           yourEditText.setText("*" + yourEditText.getText().toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: I want this happen as the user is typing. I try to use TextWatcher. I try to count all lines, get each as String, add prefix and then using StringBuilder add all lines in one String, then clear text ans set Text again.